# Biztalk Bre rules are not fired

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-rule-engine

I have a condition where rule two depends on rule one, in order to get the updated value, I am updating the Root node.

Please see the link from Microsoft forum [Biztalk Bre conditions met but rules not fired](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1415cd7a-0e45-447e-ba48-2765cf9e68b5/biztalk-bre-conditions-met-but-rules-not-fired?forum=biztalkgeneral)

I am using update statement in rule one.

Input is `class1.name = vinay, class1.age =12 ,class2.years = 12, class2.months=12`

**Rule1:**

```
if class1.name = name

then class1.age = 32

class2.years = 32

update: **BOM**
```

**Rule2**

```
if class2. years =32

then class2.months = 322
```

Rule 1 supplies values to rule 2

Comment: Don't you mean your rule is class1.name = vinay?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to document type And also each class being individual schema, we need to update class1, class2 instead of update BOM